# .Net Core 3.1 - Stuck on connection.open() in the Linux while connecting Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

.Net Core 3.1 stuck on the **connection.open()** method call on Linux machine as well as Docker, it is working sometimes and stuck sometimes. Don't know where is the actual issue.

I am using **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** library for the connection, I have tried **System.Data.SqlClient** too getting the same issue.

Even tried to downgrade the .Net core version from 3.1 to 2.2 and 2.1

Tried with SQL Server **2008 R2 SP3**, **2012** and **2017**.

It is working fine on the Windows machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2 SP3

Comment: I hate to say it, but: extended support for 2008 R2 ended over 6 months ago (and there's a clue in the name "2008"). If it doesn't work because of, sa, a protocol problem: I don't see anyone jumping to fix it. Is this simply a firewall problem by any chance?

Comment: It is also not working on Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by changing the Connection Timeout from 0 to 30.

Connection Timeout 0 makes it stuck.